# How WebSocket server handles multiple incoming connection requests?

Tags: http, websocket, spring-websocket

According to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh969243.aspx):

> The HTTP Upgrade header requests that the server ***switch the
>   application-layer protocol from HTTP to the WebSocket protocol***.
>
> The client handshake established a HTTP-on-TCP connection between IE10
>   and server. After the server returns its 101 response, the
>   application-layer protocol switches from HTTP to WebSockets which uses
>   the previously established TCP connection.
>
> ***HTTP is completely out of the picture*** at this point. Using the
>   lightweight WebSocket wire protocol, messages can now be sent or
>   received by either endpoint at any time.

So, my understanding is, after the 1st client finished handshake with the server, the server's 80 port will be ***monopolized*** by the WebSocket protocol. And the **HTTP is no longer working on 80 port**.

So how could the 2nd client exchange handshake with the server. ***After all the WebSocket handshake is in HTTP format.***

### ADD 1

Thanks for all the answers so far. They are really helpful.

Now I understand that the same server's 80 port is ***shared*** by multiple `TCP` connections. And this sharing is totally OK because `TCP` connections are identified by a 5-element tuple as `Jan-Philip Gehrcke` pointed out.

I'd like to add a few thoughts.

Both `WebSocket` and `HTTP` are merely application level protocols. *Usually* they both rely on the `TCP` protocol as their transport.

### Why choose port 80?

WebSocket design intentionally choose server's port 80 for *both handshake and following communication*. I think the designer wants to make WebSocket communication *look like* normal HTTP communication ***from the transport level's perspective (i.e. the server port number is still 80)***. But according to `jfriend00`'s answer, this trick doesn't always fool the network infrastructures.

### How does the protocol shift from *HTTP* to *WebSocket* happen?

From RFC 6455 - WebSocket protocol

> Basically it is intended to be as close to just exposing raw TCP to
>   script as possible given the constraints of the Web. It’s also
>   designed in such a way that its servers can share a port with HTTP
>   servers, by having its handshake be a valid HTTP Upgrade request. One
>   could conceptually use other protocols to establish client-server
>   messaging, but the intent of WebSockets is to provide a relatively
>   simple protocol that can coexist with HTTP and deployed HTTP
>   infrastructure (such as proxies) and that is as close to TCP as is
>   safe for use with such infrastructure given security considerations,
>   with targeted additions to simplify usage and keep simple things
>   simple (such as the addition of message semantics).

So I think I am wrong on the following statement:

> The handshake request *mimic* HTTP request but the communication that
>   follows don't. The handshake request arrives at the server on port 80.
>   **Because it's 80 port, server will treat it with HTTP protocol. And that's why the WebSocket handshake request must be in HTTP format.** 
>   If so, I think the HTTP protocol **MUST** be modified/extended to
>   recognize those WebSocket-specific things. Otherwise it won't realize
>   it should ***yield to*** WebSocket protocol.

I think it should be understood like this:

> WebSocket communication starts with a **valid** HTTP request from
>   client to server. So it is the server that follows the HTTP protocol
>   to parse the handshake request and **identify** the begging for
>   protocol change. And it is the server that switches the protocol. So
>   HTTP protocol doesn't need to change. HTTP protocol doesn't even need
>   to know about WebSocket.

### WebSocket and Comet

So WebSocket is different from [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technologies in that WebSoket doesn't limit itself within the current HTTP realm to solve the bi-directional communication issue.

### ADD 2

A related question: [How does a browser establish connection with a web server on 80 port? Details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387835/how-does-a-browser-establish-connection-with-a-web-server-on-80-port)

Comment: The WebSocket handshake is "in HTTP format" but that does not mean it uses HTTP. ["The handshake resembles HTTP so that servers can handle HTTP connections as well as WebSocket connections on the same port. However the specific fields involved, and what follows after the handshake, do not conform to the HTTP protocol."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake)

Comment: And how do you think this same problem is solved, ignoring WebSockets? That is: what do think happens when a server listening for HTTP requests on port 80 receives multiple incoming HTTP requests?

Comment: @MattBall I think I understand how multiple requests on port 80. Server just accepts each of them and using separate TCP connections to serve them. In my oritinal question, I just have an impression that first it's HTTP that is working on port 80, then per the client's UPGRADE request, the HTTP protocol is replaced by WebSocket. And thus the question in my post.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Your question is great!

I would like to try to answer it from the point of view involving the system calls `listen()` and `accept()`. Understanding the behavior of these two calls I think is quite insightful and sufficient to answer your question.

#### Spoiler: we can answer your question by looking into how TCP/IP works :-)

For the core part of the question, we do not even need to distinguish "normal" HTTP and WebSockets. The common ground is *TCP over IP*.

Sending an HTTP request requires an established TCP/IP connection between two parties (I have tried to elaborate on that a bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270860/145400)).

In case of a simple web browser / web server scenario

1. first, a TCP connection is established between both (initiated by the client)
2. then an HTTP request is sent through that TCP connection (from the client to the server)
3. then an HTTP response is sent through the *same* TCP connection (in the other direction, from the server to the client)

After this exchange, the underlying TCP connection is not needed anymore and  usually becomes destroyed/disconnected. In case of a so-called "HTTP Upgrade request" (which can be thought of as: "hey, server! Please upgrade this to a WebSocket connection!"), the underlying TCP connection just goes on living, and the WebSocket communication goes through the very same TCP connection that was created initially (step (1) above).

This hopefully clarifies that the key difference between WebSocket and HTTP is a switch in a high-level protocol (from HTTP toward WebSocket) **without changing the underlying transport channel (a TCP/IP connection).**

## Handling multiple IP connection attempts through the same socket, how?

This is a topic I was once struggling with myself and that many do not understand because it is a little non-intuitive. However, the concept actually is quite simple when one understands how the basic socket-related system calls provided by the operating system are working.

First, one needs to appreciate that an IP connection is *uniquely* defined by **five** pieces of information:

**IP:PORT of Machine A** and **IP:PORT of Machine B** and **the protocol (TCP or UDP)**

Now, *socket* objects are often thought to represent a connection. But that is not entirely true. They may represent different things: they can be active or passive. A socket object in **passive/listen** mode does something pretty special, and that is important to answer your question.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen says:

> listen() marks the socket referred to by sockfd as a passive socket,
> that is, as a socket that will be used to accept incoming connection
> requests using accept(2).

That is, we can create a **passive** socket that listens for incoming connection requests. By definition, such a socket can never represent a connection. It just listens for connection requests.

Let's head over to `accept()` (http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept):

> The accept() system call is used with connection-based socket types
> (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_SEQPACKET). It extracts the first connection
> request on the queue of pending connections for the listening socket,
> sockfd, creates a new connected socket, and returns a new file
> descriptor referring to that socket. The newly created socket is not
> in the listening state. The original socket sockfd is unaffected by
> this call.

Let's digest this carefully, I think this now really answers your question.

`accept()` does not change the state of the **passive** socket created before. It returns an **active (connected)** socket (such a socket then represents the five pieces of information states above -- simple, right?).

Usually, this newly created active socket object is then handed off to another process or thread or just "entity" that takes care of the connection. After `accept()` has returned this connected socket object, `accept()` can be called *again* on the passive socket, and again and again -- something that is known as **accept loop**.

But calling `accept()` takes time, right? Can't it miss incoming connection requests? There is more essential information in the just-quoted help text: there is a queue of pending connection requests! It is handled automatically by the TCP/IP stack of your operating system.

That means that while `accept()` can only deal with incoming connection requests **one-by-one**, no incoming request will be missed even when they are incoming at a high rate or (quasi-)simultaneously. One could say that the behavior of `accept()` is rate-limiting the frequency of incoming connection requests your machine can handle. However, this is a fast system call and in practice, other limitations hit in first -- usually those related to handling all the connections that have been accepted *so far*.

Comment: your answer is the best one so far, and very instructive too! This is actually more a TCP related question than a HTTP/Websocket related one. The handover performed upon receiving the HTTP UPGRADE request doesn't have anything to do with how HTTP and/or Websockets services can serve multiple connections on the same TCP port.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I learned a lot from your post and really appreciate your detailed explanation. But I can only mark one answer. Sorry for that. Add 1 instead. :)

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, Today I re-read your answer. I have a impression that `the server-client distinction only exists before the establishment of connection`, once the `accept()` is called and another server port is granted, the client and server are merely `equal peers` talking to each other over an `active` TCP connection.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke On the server side, a port switch happens from 80 to some other port, say 9999. So server's `socketfd = (client IP, client port, server IP, 9999, tcp)`, but client's `socketfd = (client IP, client port, server IP, 80, tcp)`. How and when does the client get to know the port change?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Oh, my bad!! The `accept()` system call just create an **active** socket, the server port 80 is not changed. So client doesn't need any port change. The socket object DOES mean more than just IP address and ports, they represent `passive/active`!

Comment: @smwikipedia No. There is no port switch.

Answer (score 26):

The relatively straightforward thing you seem to be missing here is that each connection to a server (in particular to your HTTP server here) ***creates it's own socket*** and then runs on that socket.  What happens on one socket is ***completely independent*** of what happens on any other socket that is currently connected.  So, when one socket is switched to the webSocket protocol, that does not change what happens to other current or incoming socket connections.  Those get to decide on their own how they will be processed.

So, open sockets can be using the webSocket protocol while other incoming connections can be regular HTTP requests or requests to create a new webSocket connection.

So, you can have this type of sequence:

1. Client A connects to server on port 80 with HTTP request to initiate a webSocket connection.  This process creates a socket between the two.
2. Server responds yes, to the upgrade to webSocket request and both client and server switch the protocol ***for this socket only*** to the webSocket protocol.
3. Client A and Server start exchanging packets using the webSocket protocol and continue to do so for the next several hours.
4. Client B connects to the same server on port 80 with a regular HTTP request.  This process creates a new socket between the two.
5. Server sees the incoming request is a normal HTTP request and sends the response.
6. When client B receives the response, the socket is closed.
7. Client C connects to the same server on port 80 with an HTTP request to upgrade to a webSocket.
8. Server responds yes, to the upgrade to webSocket request and both client and server switch the protocol ***for this socket only*** to the webSocket protocol.
9. At this point, there are two open sockets using the webSocket protocol that can be communicating and the server is still accepting new connections that can be either regular HTTP requests or can be requests for an updrade to the webSocket protocol.

So, at all times, the Server is still accepting new connections on port 80 and those new connections can either be regular HTTP requests or can be HTTP requests that are a request to upgrade to the webSocket protocol (and thus start a webSocket connection).  And, while all this is going on, webSocket connections that have already been established are communicating over their own socket using the webSocket protocol.

The webSocket connection and communication scheme was very carefully designed to have these charateristics:

1. No new port was required.  The incoming port (most commonly port 80) could be used for both regular HTTP requests and for webSocket communication.
2. Because no new port was required, changes in firewalls or other networking infrastructure were "usually" not required.  As it turns out this isn't always the case because some proxies or caches that are expecting HTTP traffic may have to be modified to handle (or avoid) the webSocket protocol traffic.
3. The same server process could easily handle both HTTP requests and webSocket requests.
4. HTTP cookies and/or other HTTP-based authentication means could be used during setup of a webSocket connection.

---

Answers to your further questions:

> 1) Why choose 80 as the default port? Does the designer want to make
>   WebSocket communication look like normal HTTP communication from the
>   transport level's perspective? (i.e. the server port is the good old
>   80).

Yes, see my points 1-4 immediately above.  webSockets can be established over existing HTTP channels so they generally require no networking infrastructure changes.  I'd add to those points that no new server or server process is required either as an existing HTTP server can simply have webSocket support added to it.

> 2) I am trying to picture how the protocol shift happens on server. I
>   image there're different software modules for handling HTTP or
>   WebSocket traffics. First server uses the HTTP module to handle the
>   normal HTTP requests. When it finds an Upgrade request, it will switch
>   to use WebSocket module.

Different server architectures will handle the division between webSocket packets and HTTP requests differently.  In some, webSocket connections might even be forwarded off to a new process.  In others, it may just be a different event handler in the same process that is registered for incoming packet traffic on the socket which is now been switched over to the webSocket protocol.  This is entirely dependent upon the web server architecture and how it chooses to process webSocket traffic.  A developer implementing the server end of a webSocket app will most likely select an existing webSocket implementation that is compatible with their particular web server architecture and then write code that works within that framework.

In my case, I selected the socket.io library that works with node.js (which is my server architecture).  That library gives me an object that supports events for newly connecting webSockets and then a set of other events for reading incoming messages or sending outgoing messages.  The details of the initial webSocket connection are all handled by the library and I don't have to worry about any of that.  If I want to require authentication before the connection is established, the socket.io library has a way for me to plug that in.  I can then receive messages from any client, send messages to any single client or broadcast info to all clients.  I'm mostly using it for broadcast to keep some info in a web page "live" so that web page display is always current.  Anytime the value changes on the server, I broadcast the new value to all connected clients.

Comment: I think the distiction between active and passive sockets is very essential for answering this question. I like your answer, but you do not explain how "So, at all times, the Server is still accepting new connections" is actually possible. I hope to have provided that piece of information in my answer.

Comment: How come that you think I think that?

Comment: "There is no such socket state.": There is such a state! That is part of TCP/IP fundamentals you should read about again. A socket can either be "passive" (i.e. listening for incoming connections, and not represent a connection) or "active" (representing a connection). Sometimes called "active open" vs. "passive open". That's fact. And the point of my answer. Has **nothing** to do with CPU and bandwidth, I do not mention these topics.

Comment: You might want to go over your books again. Or use the programming language of your choice for creating a basic IP connection. Server side: You first create a socket, you put it into listen mode (make it passive!), and start accepting incoming connections. The initially created socket is not changed by this, it still is **passive**. All contained in my answer, just read it.

Comment: *"Whatever passive sockets you are talking do not seem to help the OP"*? The question of the OP is *"How WebSocket server handles multiple incoming connection requests?"*. He specifies: *"the server's 80 port will be monopolized by the WebSocket protocol. And the HTTP is no longer working on 80 port."*. The concept of the **passive socket** (or call it listening/accepting socket) is solving his mystery. Entirely.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. Maybe I didn't make my question as clear as possible. But you still get my point  :) .  I updated my questions. The **bold** parts are those I am not fully sure. Could you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00 In your example sequence step `2` and `4`, who should determine the request is a regular HTTP request or a WebSocket handshake? Is it the HTTP protocol software which is extended to accommodate WebSocket?

Comment: @smwikipedia - See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers) if you want to see a sample webSocket initiation.  It starts out as a plain HTTP request that has a custom header on it that identifies it as a request to upgrade to the webSocket protocol.  So, a web server that supports the webSocket protocol will be looking at every incoming request to see if that custom header is there.  If not, it processes it as a normal web request.  If it is there, then it initiates the conversion to the webSocket protocol for that particular connection only.

Comment: @smwikipedia - when you ask about the bold parts are you asking about the bold parts in your question or the bold parts in my answer?  If in your question, which bold parts do you still need help with (as you have more than a dozen)?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry for the typing issue. My questions are: `1) `why choose 80 as the default port? Does the designer want to make WebSocket communication look like normal HTTP communication from the transport level's perspective? (i.e. the server port is the good old 80). `2)` I am trying to picture how the protocol shift happens on server. I image there're different software modules for handling HTTP or WebSocket traffics. First server uses the HTTP module to handle the normal HTTP requests. When it finds an Upgrade request, it will switch to use WebSocket module.

Comment: @jfriend00  You rock! Thanks! I will take some time for a thorough understanding. I hope there's no more struggling for me. :)

Comment: @jfriend00 And btw, if you have time, could you take a look at another question of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523914/whats-the-status-of-websocket-protocol

Comment: @jfriend00 Just one more question. If I want to write a WebSocket server from scratch with only TCP socket programming, I think I ONLY need to take care of a **tiny portion** of HTTP protocol, i.e. for the initial HTTP Upgrade handshake and no other part of HTTP. And then the whole WebSocket protocol. And this server can run standalone on any port I want. Right?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question: simultaneous Websocket and HTTP connections to port 80 are handled...

### Exactly the same way simultaneous HTTP connections to port 80 are handled!

That means: Upon satisfactory TCP handshake, the service listening on serviceip:80 proceeds to spawn a new process or thread and handover all the communications for that connection to it  (or just serves the request by executing the callback associated with that event as the asynchronous nodejs does, as jfriend00 correctly pointed out).

Then waits or handles the next incoming request in queue.

If you want to know what part HTTP 1.1 and the UPGRADE request play on all of this, this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh969243.aspx) on it leaves it very clear:

> The WebSocket Protocol has two parts: a handshake to establish the
>   upgraded connection, then the actual data transfer. First, a client
>   requests a websocket connection by using the "Upgrade: websocket" and
>   "Connection: Upgrade" headers, along with a few protocol-specific
>   headers to establish the version being used and set-up a handshake.
>   The server, if it supports the protocol, replies with the same
>   "Upgrade: websocket" and "Connection: Upgrade" headers and completes
>   the handshake. Once the handshake is completed successfully, data
>   transfer begins.

Only Websocket services are usually not built into the web server so not really intended to listen in port 80, just accessible through it thanks to the web server's transparent forwarding. Apache Web server does that using [mod_proxy_wstunnel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html).

Of course you can also have a web server with a built in web sockets implementation: [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html), for example.

The main thing here is: Websocket protocol is not HTTP. It serves a different purpose. It is an independent application-layer communication protocol also built on top of TCP (although TCP isn't necessary the requirement, but a transport layer protocol that fits the requirements of the Websockets application layer protocol).

A Websocket service is a PARALLEL service running along with a web server service.

It uses the Websocket protocol, for which modern web browsers have support, implementing the client part of the interface.

You set up or build a Websocket service in order to establish persistent, non-HTTP connections between Websocket clients (usually web browsers) and that service.

The main advantage is: The Websocket service can SEND a message to the client *whenever it needs to* ("one of you buddies has connected!" "your team just scored a goal!"), instead of having to wait for the client's *explicit REQUEST* for an update.

You can establish a persistent connection using HTTP 1.1, but HTTP is not meant for anything other than serving a set of resources *UPON REQUEST* and then close the connection.

Up until recently, before Websockets' support was available in all major browsers, you had only two choices for implementing real time updates on a web application:

- Implementing AJAX long polling requests, which is a painful and inefficient process.
- Using / building a browser plugin (for example a Java applet support plugin) in order to be able to establish a non-HTTP connection with you updates service, which is more efficient but even more painful than long polling.

In terms of the service's shared listening port (which can be any TCP port, and it doesn't even have to be open to the internet, since most web servers support transparent forwarding of web socket connections), it works exactly as any other TCP service: the service just listens on it and when the TCP handshake is over a TCP socket exists for the service to communicate with the client.

As usual, all connections to a service listening on a particular TCP socket (server_ip:service_TCP_port) will be differentiated when assigned a unique client_ip:client_TCP_port pair, the client_TCP_port being randomly chosen by the client amongst its available TCP ports).

If you are still in doubt about the HTTP->Websocket application protocol handover happening upon Websocket connection handshake and how it doesn't have anything to do with the underlying TCP connection, I refer you to [Jan-Philip Gehrcke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28518466/1060686), which is very clear an instructive and probably what you were actually looking for.

Comment: But according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket: *In addition, the communications are done over TCP port number **80**, which is of benefit for those environments which block non-web Internet connections using a firewall.*

Comment: yes, they are. But only the web server is listening on port 80. In the most common scenario any web-socket communications are forwarded to the web socket service by the web server, and the web socket service can be listening on any port. The alternative is using a different public IP for the web socket service on port 80 but this can generate all kinds of trouble and it is not seen nearly as often.

Comment: If randomly chosen ports are chosen, how could the communication pass through firewalls? Or the communication still go through the TCP 80 port, the WebSocket ports is encapsulated within. The web server who listens on the port 80 will check the encapsulated port and forward it to WebSocket service?

Comment: Random TCP ports are chosen for each connection on the client, not the server. (I apologize for the lapsus). Anyway, usually the webserver will forward websocket connections to the websocket service's listening address (ip:port), so the websocket service will be behind a firewall, listening on any port the service admin decides to use for its deployment, not necessarily port 80.

Comment: The part in your first paragraph about "spawn a new thread or process" is only one way of processing an incoming socket and is not required and is not the way that all servers do it.  For example, node.js does not do it that way.

Comment: good point, although nodejs wouldn't be the web server or websockets implementation (the implementation depends on the module) and in practice you still need to spawn multiple processes to handle high load.

Comment: Even in high scale nodejs implementations, there is never a new process for each socket as you have described.  That just isn't required to have both both webSocket and HTTP connections running on the same port so that part of your answer is just misleading because it is not a required part of the solution to the OP's question in any way.

Comment: Not a new process per socket of course, but multiple processes indeed.

Comment: Anyway, you are right and I've updated my answer to point that out.

Comment: I also like your answer, but you do not explain how the very same "socket" can accept multiple connections. Important here: there are different types of sockets, and one of them is the **passive** one. It does *not* represent a connection, but just listens for new ones. I have clarified this in my answer.

Comment: Yes, exaclty that. I assumed the TCP socket creation process was understood and moved on to explain what the web server was doing to establish and serve the HTTP and Websocket connections in the application layer and how the services are usually deployed, but the important part of the question was underneath all of that. Nevertheless the sum of both answers make a pretty nice introduction to websockets, I believe! :-)

Comment: @elcodedocle If I use a different port for WebSocket rather than 80, does it ruin the whole purpose of using existing web/HTTP infrastructures? And it no longer fits the name **Web**Socket.  If I use WebSocket over other ports, why not just use TCP directly? Or is there any special benefits in the WebSocket protocol itself?

Comment: First: TCP is a transport layer. It deals with packets and send/recv buffers, not messages. Whole other animal (check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945345/differences-between-tcp-sockets-and-web-sockets-one-more-time?lq=1). Second: web is HTTP(S), not port 80. And lastly: accesible through port 80 of the web server, but implemented as a differentiated service on any port, so the web server uses something like Apache's  mod_proxy_wstunnel for transparent forwarding (which introduces little to no overhead and is super easy to set up, by the way)

Comment: So the browser sees both the HTTP web server and the Websocket service on port 80, regardless of where the Websocket service is listening. Is that clear enough?

Comment: And why bother with web server to websockets service transparent forwarding instead of choosing a consolidated option? Well, in my experience it provides an extra layer of security, load balancing (just as apache web server when put in front of Tomcat, for example) and fault tolerance (real time services tend to be easily saturated on unexpected traffic peaks. That doesn't mean your web server should collapse too and stop serving pages!)

Comment: Plus it lets you switch between different technologies: It is very common to have a nodejs websockets service to serve a site using a PHP CMS such as Drupal or Wordpress. Why? Because nodejs is awesome at real time and websockets on PHP kinda suck at this point (although progress is being made and they are getting there, they are not even part of the standard library yet: http://socketo.me/).

Answer (score 2):

It's quite a simple concept, so let me try to describe it in simple terms in case some other lost soul wants to grasp it without having to read all those long explanations.

**Multiple connections**

1. The web server starts listening for connections. This happens:

   - The main process of the web server opens a passive socket in state `listen` on port `80`, e.g. `9.9.9.9:80` (`9.9.9.9` is the server IP and `80` is the port).
2. The browser makes a request to port `80` on the server. This happens:

   - The Operating System (in short OS) allocates a random outbound port on the client, say: `1.1.1.1:6747` (`1.1.1.1` is the client IP and `6747` is the random port).
   - The OS sends a data packet with the source address `1.1.1.1:6747` and destination address `9.9.9.9:80`. It goes through various routers and switches and arrives at the destination server.
3. The server receives the packet. This happens:

   - The server OS sees that the packet's destination address is one of its own IP addresses and based on the destination port passes it on to the application associated with port `80`.
   - The main process of the web server accepts the connection creating a new active socket. Then it usually forks a new child process, which takes over the active socket. The passive socket stays open to accept new incoming connections.

Now every packet send from the server to the client will have those addresses:

- source: `9.9.9.9:1553`; destination: `1.1.1.1:80`

And every packet send from the client to the server will have those addresses:

- source: `1.1.1.1:80`; destination: `9.9.9.9:1553`

**HTTP -> WebSocket handshake**

HTTP is a text-based protocol. See the [HTTP wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) for the list of available commands. The browser sends one of those commands and the web server responds accordingly.

WebSocket is not based on HTTP. It's a binary protocol where multiple streams of messages can be send in both directions at the same time (full-duplex mode). Because of that it would not be possible to establish a WebSocket connection directly without introducing a new HTTP standard, like for example [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2). But that would be only possible if:

1. WebSocket supported [HTTP verbs/requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)
2. There was a new dedicated port different than `80` for WebSocket-specific communication.

The first wasn't in scope for the protocol and the second would break the existing web infrastructure. Because a client/browser can establish multiple HTTP connections with the same server, switching some of them from HTTP to WebSocket is the best of both worlds - keep the same port `80` but allow a different protocol than HTTP. The switch happens through [protocol handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake) initiated by the client.

Comment: Thanks for the vivid answer! Just one more question about some detail. At first, client sends package to server 9.9.9.9:`80`, but once the server accepts it, client will send package to server 9.9.9.9:`1553`. So how does the **client** get to know the server target port change? Or let me put it this way, since the server port is changed, how could client still recognize it as the same application it was talking to.

Comment: I agree that client need to pick a random local port to send data to server. But does server need to also pick a random local port?  I think the whole tuple `(client ip, client random port, server ip, 80, tcp)` suffices to uniquely represent an IP connection between server and a certain client. So server doesn't need to pick a random local port. But anyway, I will use wireshark to do a experiment and get back later.

Comment: I used Wireshark to analyze the TCP packet flow between a browser and a server. **No random outbound port is picked on the server side** (i.e. the 1553 port in your example).  Only the random port for client. Server always use the port it listens on (8080 in my scenario). So I don't agree with your observation 3.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The server does not allocate a new port to the incoming connection. It uses the same port as the listening port.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Just corrected the answer. I mistakenly associated ports with sockets. The server needs to open a new socket for each connection, not a port, and the destination port in every new socket remains the same.

Comment: Your point 1 consists of a *non sequitur:* the number of child processes has nothing to do with whether or not there exists a port in LISTEN state. In point 2 you entirely overlook HTTP keepalive as the default. In point, the tuple describes the connection, not just the socket, and the kernel needs the entire tuple, not just the client part of it. There are far too many errors here, and far too much irrelevant waffle that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP, deleted the waffle that doesn't answer the question. Now it's short and concise. Any other errors? Thanks for feedback. I wasn't going to give a detailed answer because that takes a few pages in a book. But I agree it may be better to skip the waffle than give misleading information.

Comment: I hope the added section about the HTTP -> WebSocket upgrade makes the answer more relevant.