# What's the status of WebSocket protocol?

Tags: http, websocket, http-headers

I see a section called [IANA Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11) in the [RFC 6455 - Web Socket Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

It defines several HTTP headers to be added to HTTP protocol. Such as [Sec-WebSocket-Key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.3.1), [Sec-WebSocket-Extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.3.2), etc.

But I didn't find these headers in the [RFC 2616 - HTTP 1.1 Protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

So are these headers definitions ready for use?

(I am not quite familiar with how RFC documents are organized. So pardon me this is a dumb question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP protocol allows for custom headers to be added to any HTTP request.  If the HTTP server doesn't know about a particular header name, it just ignores it.  The initiation of a webSocket connection adds some custom headers to its HTTP request that are not standard HTTP-defined header names, but they are formatted as standard HTTP headers (as defined in section 4.2 of RFC 2616) and thus are safely ignored by any HTTP server that doesn't understand them.

As Julian pointed out in comments, you can see the Sec-WebSocket-xxx headers registered [here in the IANA header registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml) and you may have already seen, the meaning of those headers are described in more detail in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.3.1).

Furthermore, [section 8.3 of RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.3) describes the general process for defining and registering new headers and the rules that they should follow (and other specifications that help define those rules).

Comment: Many thanks! Right on target! And you are a very nice person. :)

Comment: Clarifying: (a) what's relevant for a header field definition is the entry in the IANA header field registry, not a particular RFC; (b) RFC 2616 has been updated by a series of new specs last year; (c) RFCs are immutable; they never change, but they may get replaced by a new RFC#.

Comment: @JulianReschke - I updated my answer to include your suggestions.

Comment: @jfriend00 Could you help me on this thread? Excuse me for making such an explicit request. Thank you again for helping me a lot on WebSocket related questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553580/websocket-and-the-origin-header-field

Comment: @smwikipedia - sorry, but I don't know the answer to that other question.  I haven't worked on origin-related stuff myself.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's OK. Thanks all the same.