# WebSocket and the Origin header field

Tags: websocket

The following is quoted from RFC6455 - WebSocket protocol.

> Servers that are not intended to process input from any web page but
>   only for certain sites SHOULD verify the |Origin| field is an origin
>   they expect. If the origin indicated is unacceptable to the server,
>   then it SHOULD respond to the WebSocket handshake with a reply
>   containing HTTP 403 Forbidden status code.
>
> The |Origin| header field protects from the attack cases when the
>   untrusted party is typically the author of a JavaScript application
>   that is executing in the context of the trusted client. The client
>   itself can contact the server and, ***via the mechanism of the |Origin|***
>   ***header field, determine whether to extend those communication***
>   ***privileges to the JavaScript application.*** The intent is not to prevent
>   non-browsers from establishing connections but rather to ensure that
>   trusted browsers under the control of potentially malicious JavaScript
>   cannot fake a WebSocket handshake.

I just cannot be sure about what the 2nd paragraph means, especially the *italic* part. Could anyone explain it a bit? Or maybe an example.

My understanding so far is like this:

- If server CAN be sure that requests DO come from **Web** pages, the ORIGIN header can be used to prevent access from un-welcomed **Web** pages.
- If server CANNOT be sure that requests come from **Web** pages, the ORIGIN header is merely advisory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding seem to be correct, but..

I would rephrase it - you can be sure, that javascript client will send proper origin header. You don't know what will be sent by other clients (and whether the value is correct or not).

This should prevent other pages to connect to "your" web socket endpoints (which is a big deal, imagine injected javascript somewhere on jsfiddle or some frequently visited page), but if you need to make sure that no other client will be able to connect to it, you'll need to introduce some other security measures.

I believe this is meant only as prevention of browser based "data stealing" or "DDoSing", nothing else; you can still do that by using some other client.

Comment: It is basically to prevent smartass.com to access your websocket server and integrate your service in your application, since WebSockets are not affected by the SOP.